# Database encryption for SQL Server 2008 Express

Tags: sql-server-express

Database encryption using TDE (Transparent data encryption) is available only for Enterprise edition and developer edition.

Is there any way to implement encryption mechanism for SQL Server 2008 Express database with out changing underlying schema of the database?

Comment: You have to be more explicit in what you're looking for. Who are you trying to protect the database from? Who needs to have access to the data and how? Where is the SQL Server Express running, on server or on client machine? Etc.

Comment: For the information data can be accessed through the client application and using sqlcmd. However there is a requirement for database encryption. I found out that it's not possible in sql express. At this point i can try to protect data from unauthorized users. For ex: other users shouldn't be able to login to sql express using windows credential and take the backup of database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use good old encrypted file system (EFS) and storing your database files on encrypted folder

Comment: So is file system encryption the only good way for sql express

Comment: Not sure, but I think it should do the job.